# Email sender python bot which can send Emails to multiple recipient with their names in message

Tags: python, pandas, csv, email, smtp

I have a csv file in which one column is name and other is email. I have to send the email to all the members listed in csv with their name from the name column in the message. Also some names does not have the email so i want to ignore that name.
[This is how my csv file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5siF.png)

So, I tried this code. It is sending the emails individually to each member but sending the same name i.e. the last one to each email address.

can anyone help me to resolve this...?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import csv
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email import *
from itertools import islice

df=pd.read_csv("emails.csv")
df.isnull()
df.isnull().sum()
df['email'].fillna("NO Email",inplace=True)

X=df.iloc[:,2].values
y=df.iloc[:,0].values


FROM= "mail@gmail.com"
TO=X
password=input("enter password:")
message= MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = FROM
message['Subject'] = "subject line"
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(FROM,password)
for j in TO:
    if(j=="NO Email"):
        #i_iter=iter(i)
        print("No email found ")#+ next(islice(i_iter,1)))
        for i in y:
            #next(i_iter)
            print("Name skip")
         continue
     else:
        i=0
        for i in range(len(y)):
            message = MIMEText("""hii..........{}""".format(y[i]))
            #i+=1
        print("Login success")
        server.sendmail(FROM,j,message.as_string())
        print("email has been send to ",j)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the original `message` inside the loop, so what you end up passing to `server.sendmail` is not a valid email message.

Probably try something like

```py
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib
import logging

FROM = "mail@gmail.com"

with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as server:
    server.starttls()
    server.login(FROM, password)
    logging.info("Login success")

    for address, recipient in zip(X, y):
        if address == "NO Email":
            logging.warning("No email found: %s", recipient)
            continue

        message = EmailMessage()
        message['From'] = FROM
        message['Subject'] = "subject line"
        message.set_content("""hii..........{}""".format(recipient))

        server.send_message(message)
        logging.info("email has been sent to %s", recipient)
```

Notice how we use `zip()` to align the two columns, and replace the rather haphazard mix of random `email` functions with, basically, the first example from https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html and also more tangentially use `logging` instead of `print` for diagnostic messages.

Comment: I *think* Gmail will require you to do `ehlo` -- twice! Once before STARTTLS and then again after.

Comment: It gives the error 
```SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first``` If i write the continue outside the if condition it runs but only send email to one person.can you please tell me how to resolve this.

Comment: Obviously don't put the `continue` outside the condition. Can you enable verbose debugging for `smtplib` and link to a paste of the resulting transcript?

Comment: Can you tell me in details how to enable that ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.set_debuglevel